# Algebra: Help with these expressions about inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$x'$ meaning transpose of vector $x$.

Let's say I have this expression:

$$(x\cdot v')^2$$

I can write it as:
$$
(x\cdot v')^2 = (x \cdot v')(x \cdot v')
$$

My question came up when I saw somewhere that
$$
(x \cdot v')(x \cdot v') = (v' \cdot x)(x \cdot v')
$$

Specially when I realized that $(x \cdot v')$ is a matrix and $(v' \cdot x)$ is a constant.
So, obviously $(x \cdot v') != (v' \cdot x)$, but they are generating the same effect multiplying $(x \cdot v')$.

**Question 1:** Could some one explain it?

Also, in theses notes that I found somewhere, it has the following:
$$
(I - U)^{-1} = I - U + U^2 - U^3 + \cdots
$$

$I$ - seems to be the identity matrix
$U$ - any matrix, maybe a symmetric matrix (I am not sure)

I have no idea where does it comes from. I trying to do some examples but the results obviously doesn't make sense.

**Question 2:** Could someone give me a hit on what this last formula suppose to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** If $x$ and $v$ are column vectors then $v'x$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix.  Multiplying by a $1 \times 1$ matrix is the same as multiplying by the scalar entry of that $1 \times 1$ matrix.  This is why $v'x$ is often thought of as being a scalar and not necessarily a matrix.

The key point is that scalar multiplication of matrices commutes with matrix multiplication.  So
$$(xv')(xv') = x(v'x)v' = (v'x)xv'$$
where in the very last step I've commuted the *scalar* $v'x$ past the matrix $x$.

**Question 2:** Yes $I$ is the identity matrix.  To decide what $U$ is you first have to decide in what context does $I + U + U^2 + \cdots$ make sense.  In general you need the expression $U^n$ to converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, but maybe that's more complicated than you'd like.  The easiest is when there is some $n$ such that $U^n = 0$ so I'll explain it in that case.

When $U^n = 0$ then the infinite expression $I + U + U^2 + \cdots$ is actually a finite expression: $I + U + U^2 + \cdots + U^{n - 1}$.  Now that it's finite you can check that
$$(I - U)(I + U + U^2 + \cdots + U^{n - 1}) = I$$
so
$$(I - U)^{-1} = I + U + U^2 + \cdots + U^{n - 1}.$$
Notice my negative signs are different from yours, there's a mistake in your formula.  You can replace $U$ with $-U$ in my formula to get
$$(I + U)^{-1} = I - U + U^2 - U^3 + \cdots + (-1)^{n - 1}U^{n - 1}$$
but that's also different that what you've written.

Comment: Thank you for the help. **Question 1** is clear for me, now. Well, about the context of **Question 2**, this is the page where I saw these expressions: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/sXWtJMb.png). I am still trying to process it.

Where does the following expression come from? Does it have a name?
$$
I + U + U^2 + U^3 + ... + U^n = 0, when \ n \to \infty
$$

Also, developing this expression: 
$$ 
(I - U)(I+U+U^{2}+...+U^{n-1}) = I \\
\Rightarrow II + IU + IU^2 + ... + IU^{-1} -UI -U^2 - ... - U^{n-1} - U^n = I\\ 
\Rightarrow I - U^n = I \\
\Rightarrow U^n = 0
$$

Is it right?

Comment: I don't know where you got that expression, nor do I know if it has a name.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just now I actually understood what you wrote on **Question 2**. Thanks again. By the way, it seems that $U$ is called [Convergent Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix).